# GWT code - how to force a tooltip with line breaks?

Tags: java, html, gwt, newline, line-breaks

I'm trying to create a tooltip with two lines on a div with GWT code.
I use the following character: `&#10;`

My code looks like this:

```
HTML myDiv = new HTML();
myDiv.setTitle("First line&#10;Second line");
```

The tooltip I get on the div is:

```
First line&#10;Second line
```

but the tooltip I want is:

```
First line
Second line
```

Question is: what do I need to change in my JAVA/GWT code?

Comment: I don't think you can with native titles.

Comment: You can write `\n` instead of `&#10;`, but I'm pretty sure that some browsers will display this as a space.

Answer (score 0):

This works!!.

```
myDiv.setTitle("First line  \n Second line");
```

Gwt title ovverides the native `title attr`

[So just for demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1374/)

Comment: I ran a quick test and it works in many browsers, but I'm certain I remember that this had different results in different browsers in the past (some turned this into a space).

Comment: How does it not work? Doesn't it compile? Does it put `\n` on the screen? A space? Some other character?

Comment: The tooltip I get is `First line\nSecond line`

Comment: @HadarZadok But I thought GWT was Java. You can't put escaped control chars in the source like that?

Comment: It is JAVA but it compiles to JavaScript and apparently HTML strings are not 'compiled'.